# How can I deserialize my JSON for C# so that I can request a specific duplicate variable?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a JSON string that I would like to de-serialize for my Unity game using C#. The string looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq5CF.png

A more basic JSON formatted version would be this, for help explaining.

```
{
 "Entries": [
    {
        "Logical": "Easy",
        "EncounterType": "Standard",
        "EnrageType": "None",
        "WaitForCameraTime": 30,
        "OfflineExpireTime": 60,
        "UI": {
            "UseShocker": true,
            "UseFlashlight": true
        },
    },
    {
        "Logical": "Medium",
        "EncounterType": "Standard",
        "EnrageType": "None",
        "WaitForCameraTime": 30,
        "OfflineExpireTime": 60,
        "UI": {
            "UseShocker": true,
            "UseFlashlight": true
        }
    },
    {
        "Logical": "Hard",
        "EncounterType": "Standard",
        "EnrageType": "None",
        "WaitForCameraTime": 30,
        "OfflineExpireTime": 60,
        "UI": {
            "UseShocker": true,
            "UseFlashlight": true
        },
    }
 ]
}
```

How can I deserialize this string for Unity (using Newtonsoft json.net or another method) so that I can request something based on the logical name? Example: the OfflineExpireTime for the Logical Medium.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, please paste in as text instead.

Comment: Seems like you need a root class with `List<Entry> Entries`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: fixed my post. sorry a bit new here.

Comment: @OrtonLGaming You have to post a real json as a text, not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, I think the easiest way is to generate a class with something like this https://json2csharp.com/

That will give you this:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class Entry
    {
        public string Logical { get; set; }
        public string EncounterType { get; set; }
        public string EnrageType { get; set; }
        public int WaitForCameraTime { get; set; }
        public int OfflineExpireTime { get; set; }
        public UI UI { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class UI
    {
        public bool UseShocker { get; set; }
        public bool UseFlashlight { get; set; }
    }
```

As the comment says you can then get it with:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

**Edit after comment:**

You can than e.g. loop through the list of Entries like this:

```cs
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

foreach (var entry in myDeserializedClass.Entries) 
{
    if (entry.Logical == "Easy")
        Debug.Log(entry.OfflineExpireTime + ", " + entry.UI.UseShocker);    
}
```

Comment: well thats good but im not sure how to then request the (for example) bool UseShocker from a specific Logical entry

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any custom classes to find property values

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

   JArray entries = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["Entries"];

    string logical = "Medium";

    // find an object you need

    var searchedObject = entries.Where(e => (string)e["Logical"] == logical).FirstOrDefault();

    // now you can select a value of a property you need

    bool UseShocker = (bool)searchedObject["UI"]["UseShocker"];

    int OfflineExpireTime = (int)searchedObject["OfflineExpireTime"];
```